# I am facing 401 with fiserv ucom all apis I do not know what is wrong with HMAC signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway, cryptojs

I am trying to make HMAC signature in node js. I am doing properly as mentioned in the documentation. But not able to create the signature. Please find the code below,

```
let computedHash = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
  CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
  key
);

computedHash.update(rawSignature);
computedHash = computedHash.finalize();
const computedHmac = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(computedHash);
```

Comment: Your code is OK - 401 doesn't mean you're doing it wrong, it means you're unauthorised

Comment: perhaps your `key` and/or `rawSignature` are incorrect or not in the correct format - do either of them look like they are hexidecimal string? or base64 string? P.S. why are you using CryptoJS in node? node has a perfectly good crypto built in

Comment: It is base64 string. I am using CryptoJs only because in the document they are using the same. I am sending rawSignature as they have mentioned in the document.

Comment: "it" ... what is "it"? key or signature? both? if they are, you need to convert from base64 first before you use them, unless CryptJS has specific methods to **accept** base64 in those arguments

Comment: I am updating hashed key in the rawSignature and then converting both into base64 string

Comment: OK, let me ask slowly ... are `key` and `rawSignature` encoded in `base64` or `hex`? ignore what you're doing with them, you've posted the code, and I can see that you are creating a HMAC-SHA256 encoded in base64 out of them - that is clear from yuor code ... I'm asking about the ***input data format***

Comment: For example ... `"Jefe"` is a regular string ... but it could also be `"SmVmZQ=="` if it's base64 encoded string ... or `4a656665` if it's a hex encoded string ... do you follow?

Comment: what is "base64 hex" .... that seems convoluted at best

Comment: Lol I am sorry actually I was trying to say like rawSignature and key both has been encoded in base64 and hex is not in the picture at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since the key and rawSignature are "base64 encoded" you need to "convert" them before using them

Perhaps this demonstration will help

```js
const expectedOutput = btoa( "5bdcc146bf60754e6a042426089575c75a003f089d2739839dec58b964ec3843".replace(/../g, (hex) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16))));
console.log("Test vector result should be");
console.log(expectedOutput);

(() => {
  // mock inputs as regular strings
  const key = "Jefe"
  const rawSignature = "what do ya want for nothing?"
  
  // --- your code  
  let computedHash = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
    CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
    key
  );

  computedHash.update(rawSignature);
  computedHash = computedHash.finalize();
  let computedHmac = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(computedHash);
  console.log("inputs are strings");
  console.log(computedHmac);
})();

(() => {
  // mock inputs as base64 encoded strings
  const key = btoa("Jefe");
  const rawSignature = btoa("what do ya want for nothing?");
  
  // --- your code  
  let computedHash = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
    CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
    key
  );

  computedHash.update(rawSignature);
  computedHash = computedHash.finalize();
  computedHmac = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(computedHash);
  console.log("inputs are base64 encoded - not decoding them where they are used");
  console.log(computedHmac);
})();
(() => {
  // mock inputs as base64 encoded strings
  const key = btoa("Jefe");
  const rawSignature = btoa("what do ya want for nothing?");
  
  // --- your code  
  let computedHash = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(
    CryptoJS.algo.SHA256,
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key))
  );

  computedHash.update(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(rawSignature)));
  computedHash = computedHash.finalize();
  computedHmac = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(computedHash);
  console.log("inputs are base64 encoded - decoding them where they are used");
  console.log(computedHmac);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it is not working.

Comment: you probably did it wrong

Comment: Issue is from their side wong credentials again thanks for your help.